# Cómo usar mariadb por fuera de un XAMPP y acceder desde ese phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

quería consultar lo siguiente: si instalo mariaDB mediante

`brew install mariadb`

me permitirá acceder por phpmyadmin? ya que tengo Xammp en mi Mac y al ajecutar el apache y apagar el mysql de xampp no tengo acceso a phpmyadmin,

me ayudarian si me brindan un manual de como instalar mariadb y como tener el entorno de phpmyadmin. no estoy seguro si es posible cuando se ejecute el xampp, espero me ayuden.

Comment: Es raro que quieras instalar MariaDB, porque es la base de datos integrada por defecto en [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html) desde hace algunos años y, en teoría, genera conflicto con MySQL Community Server, por lo que no puedes tener ambos instalados. ¿Qué salida obtienes si en terminal ejecutas `mysql -V`?

Comment: XAMPP es una familia feliz que si quieres separarla se pondrá mas que renuente. Si buscas problemas, los vas a encontrar! ;)

Comment: Hola, si siempre usaba mysql de Xampp para hacer mis proyectos pero de pronto no podia hacer conexiones a base de datos desde aplicaciones y por eso pase a tener mariadb nativo en la Mac por ello me dejaba hacer el proceso pero mas no tenia entorno phpmyadmin solo consola a lo cual se me hacia un poco tedioso si queria actualizar a gran escala, y de echo ahora cuando quise volver a usar xampp ya no levantaba y con ayuda de @AlfaBravo al parecer se resolvio el mysql de xampp y sobre tu pregunta esta: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.8.3-MariaDB, for osx10.17 (arm64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: pero me gustaria poder trabajar con mariaDB nativo y con entorno phpmyadmin.. no se si sea posible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La cosa es que, hasta donde me da la memoria, phpMyAdmin crea sus propias tablas en una BD en ese mysql. Apagar la BD hace que no haya acceso a los datos de configuración de phpMyAdmin y tal.

No sé si sea tan transparente (porque no sé qué versión de mysql y de mariadb tienes), pero podríás resolver haciendo algo como:

0. detener el mariadb, iniciar el mysql del xampp
1. en la carpeta xampp/mysql/data copia la subcarpeta `phpmyadmin` adentro de la carpeta `data` en mariadb. Busca esta carpeta origen prendiendo el mysql, entrando a phpmyadmin y ejecutando SELECT @@datadir`
   1.5) Detener el mysql del xampp
2. En el archivo `xampp/phpadmin/config.inc.php` (líneas aproximadas) edita lo siguiente:

   line 21 ajusta la clave
   lines 31-32 ajusta el usuario
3. reiniciar xampp y confirmartque el mysql del xampp está detenido
4. iniciar mariadb

Por favor, **haz backup de todo** antes de mover cosas. Esto puede dañar tu instalación de xampp.

Comment: Hola, te reiferes a esto correcto?https://prnt.sc/CiZJRMnEFQ3U

Comment: adicional a eso cuando quiero ingresar a mariadb me da ese error: https://prnt.sc/JSC7vv4bqKNE

Comment: sobre el paso 2 que es de la carpeta esto no existe: https://prnt.sc/hDzaIFpWHbo_

Comment: Si tienes cosas por adicional, por favor edita tu pregunta y añádelas (no borres, ve añadiendo). Y eso que te sale ya es de que configures tu mariadb para que te deje autenticar local

Comment: @joseph cambié el orden de los pasos para que revises primero dónde están tus datos de la BD y los puedas mover

Comment: ahi ejecute por phpmyadmin me da la ruta siguiente pero no llego a ubicar la carpeta "data" https://prnt.sc/2lufDZw75nZL, y es la carpeta "phpmyadmin" que se debe de copiar que haces mención?